# Browserify: App Logic in Bundled Source or Separate?

Tags: javascript, web, single-page-application, browserify, static-site

Getting started with a SPA static site web app project centered around a library only available on NPM. I'm looking into using Browserify in my build process for the first time. Should I build out my web app logic in the precompiled source with the `require` statements, then compile and have one file, or should I expose functions through `window.functionName` and have my app logic be separate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build out your app logic in a precompiled source with `import` statements. What benefit do you get from exposing functions on the window object? It's usually not recommended.